# Проблемы с сайтом. Циклическое перенаправление на странице

Tags: поддержка, статус-отклонено

У меня возникла проблема: я не могу отвечать на вопросы. Я пытаюсь открыть вопрос, но мне вы выдает следующее:

**Циклическое перенаправление на странице**

**При соединении с rus.stackexchange.com произошла ошибка.**

**Эта проблема может возникать при отключении или запрещении принятия кук.**

То же самое в Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Серж, администрация сайта не смогла уделить внимание вашему вопросу, в чем, видимо, есть и моя вина. Приношу извинения.

Я надеюсь, что описанное вами затруднение исчезло, однако, если этого не произошло:

1. Попробуйте почистить данные сайтов (cookie, etc.).
2. Смените браузер: сохраняется ли проблема?
3. Попробуйте заходить на сайт не из поисковой выдачи, а напрямую — по адресу https://rus.stackexchange.com/.

Еще раз прошу вашего прощения за промедление. Буду рад помочь, если вопросы остались.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Проблема решилась в тот же день. Но причина, по-видимому, была не в устройстве, а скорее связана с работой сайта. Все предложенные вами методы я испробовал, но ничего не помогло. Заходил с т/ф, как со своего, так и с другого, но проблема  не решилась.Даже заходил на сайт с другого профиля ( через фейсбук друга) проблема была та же. Спустя час, два, проблема решилась сама по себе.